# Simple Generators

Tags: haskell, f#, ocaml, yield, loops

This code comes from a paper called ["Lazy v. Yield"](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~sabry/papers/yield-pp.pdf). Its about a way to decouple producers and consumer of streams of data. I understand the Haskell portion of the code but the O'Caml/F# eludes me. I don't understand this code for the following reasons:

What kind of behavior can I expect from a function that takes as argument an exception and returns unit?

How does the consumer project into a specific exception? (what does that mean?)

What would be an example of a consumer?

```ml
module SimpleGenerators

type 'a gen        = unit -> 'a
type producer      = unit gen
type consumer      = exn -> unit  (* consumer will project into specific exception *)
type 'a transducer = 'a gen -> 'a gen 

let yield_handler : (exn -> unit) ref = 
    ref (fun _ -> failwith "yield handler is not set")

let iterate (gen : producer) (consumer : consumer) : unit = 
    let oldh = !yield_handler in
    let rec newh x =
        try 
            yield_handler := oldh
            consumer x
            yield_handler := newh
        with e -> yield_handler := newh; raise e
    in
    try
        yield_handler := newh
        let r = gen () in
        yield_handler := oldh
        r
    with e -> yield_handler := oldh; raise e
```

Comment: OK, so examples are found in the repo which is linked to in the paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the paper, so others will probably be more enlightening.  Here are some quick answers/guesses in the meantime.

A function of type `exn -> unit` is basically an exception handler.

Exceptions can contain data.  They're quite similar to polymorphic variants that way--i.e., you can add a new exception whenever you want, and it can act as a data constructor.

It looks like the consumer is going to look for a particular exception(s) that give it the data it wants.  Others it will just re-raise.  So, it's only looking at a projection of the space of possible exceptions (I guess).

Answer (score 3):

I think the OCaml sample is using a few constructs and design patterns that you would not typically use in F#, so it is quite OCaml-specific. As Jeffrey says, OCaml programs often use exceptions for control flow (while in F# they are only used for *exceptional* situations).

Also, F# has really powerful *sequence expressions* mechanism that can be used quite nicely to separate producers of data from the consumers of data. I did not read the paper in detail, so maybe they have something more complicated, but a simple example in F# could look like this:

```
// Generator: Produces infinite sequence of numbers from 'start'
// and prints the numbers as they are being generated (to show I/O behaviour)
let rec numbers start = seq { 
  printfn "generating: %d" start
  yield start
  yield! numbers (start + 1) }
```

A simple consumer can be implemented using `for` loop, but if we want to consume the stream, we need to say how many elements to consume using `Seq.take`:

```
// Consumer: takes a sequence of numbers generated by the 
// producer and consumes first 100 elements 
let consumer nums = 
  for n in nums |> Seq.take 100 do
    printfn "consuming: %d" n
```

When you run `consumer (numbers 0)` the code starts printing:

```
generating: 0
consuming: 0
generating: 1
consuming: 1
generating: 2
consuming: 2
```

So you can see that the effects of producers and consumers are interleaved. I think this is quite simple & powerful mechanism, but maybe I'm missing the point of the paper and they have something even more interesting. If so, please let me know! Although I think the idiomatic F# solution will probably look quite similar to the above.

Comment: Tomas, thank you for sharing this. This answers a question that I have yet to ask. I think the main advantage claimed in the paper is speed and simplicity of implementation (based on the type representations). I was just curious about the way the code worked. Thanks again.